# Distinct counting indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a customer dataframe, with  their Member IDs as index.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Mbr ID':['ID0001','ID0002','ID0003','ID0004'],
                 'Receipts':[3,5,12,5],                 
                 'Spending':[130,22,313,46],
                 'Grade':['A','B','A','B']             
                 })
df=df.set_index(['Mbr ID'])
```

[image]

I am trying to analyze the dataframe by grades, and want to see how many unique IDs there are within each grade. But I run into problem with counting Mbr IDs, as the column is used as Index.

```
agg_func={'Customer':pd.Series.nunique,'Receipts':np.sum,'Spending':np.sum}
df.groupby('Grade').agg(agg_func)
```

> KeyError: 'Mbr ID'

What should I normally do in this situation?

Comment: maybe don't drop the column `Mbr ID` from the dataframe ? `df=df.set_index(['Mbr ID'], drop=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `lambda` instead

```
agg_func = {
    'Grade': lambda s: s.index.nunique(),
    'Receipts': 'sum',
    'Spending': 'sum'
}
df.groupby('Grade').agg(agg_func).rename(columns={'Grade': 'Customer'})
```

[image]